# MySQL Update reports error, What am I missing?

Tags: python, mysql

I noticed a few posts on SO regarding MySQL updates using python and still cannot seem to get this correct.

```
def updateEmployee(employee):
    print employee["firstName"]+" "+employee["lastName"]+" "+employee["nameN"]
    cursor = db.cursor()
    if(len(employee["nameN"]) > 0):
        cursor.execute("""
                UPDATE `employee` 
                SET `employeeID`=%s, `parentID`=%s, `firstName`=%s, `title`=%s, `locCode`=%s,
```

(25)

```
                WHERE  `employee`.`nameN`=%s 
                """, (employee["employeeID"], employee["parentID"], employee["firstName"], employee["title"], employee["locCode"], employee["nameN"]))
        if(cursor.rowcount > 0 ):
            print "updated"
        else:
            c.execute("""
                INSERT INTO `employee`
                (`employeeID`, `parentID`, `nameN`, `firstName`, `alias`, `lastName`, `title`, `department`, `phone`, `areaMission`, `leadershipStyle`, `employeeType`, `coreFunc1`, `coreFunc2`, `coreFunc3`, `address`, `locCode`,`posOrg`)
                VALUES 
                (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
                """, (employee["employeeID"], employee["parentID"], employee["nameN"], employee["firstName"], "", employee["lastName"], employee["title"], "", employee["phone"], '', '', '', '', '', '', '', employee["locCode"], ''))

            if(c.rowcount > 0):
                db.commit()
                print "inserted"
            else:
                print "insert failed"
    else:
        print "missing nameN"
```

Resulting Error which appaers on line 25 (updateEmployee) which for reference has (25) in front of the line above.

```
[chris@apps ~]$ ./adjust.py
Linda Adam adam.804
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./adjust.py", line 89, in <module>
    processCSV(fileName)
  File "./adjust.py", line 14, in processCSV
    updateEmployee(employee)
  File "./adjust.py", line 25, in updateEmployee
    WHERE  `employee`.`nameN`=%s """, (employee["employeeID"], employee["parentID"], employee["firstName"], employee["title"], employee["locCode"], employee["nameN"]))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 35, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE  `employee`.`nameN`='adam.804'' at line 3")
```

It appears I am ending up with an extra ' at the "WHERE clause" but I do not understand how this could be?

The employee object I am using when this fails is defined as:

```
{
    'employeeID': '1111', 
    'firstName': 'Linda', 
    'title': 'Systems Manager', 
    'nameN': 'adam.804', 
    'lastName': 'Adam', 
    'locCode': 'TNC', 
    'phone': '555-555-5555', 
    'parentID': '2222', 
    'room': ''
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an extra comma before your WHERE clause.

An update should look like this:

```
update foo
set a = 1,
b = 2
where type = 0
```

I think yours looks like this:

```
update foo
set a = 1,
b = 2,
where type = 0
```

Comment: That did seem to fix it, any suggestion on whether or not I am using rowcount correctly?  Basically I want to try update, if update fails I want to do an insert.  Perhaps I am going about this wrong ?

Comment: Hi Chris. I didn't look that closely at your query before. If you're trying to do an upsert, you should take a look at `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment, helpful indeed.